# No image displayed when sharing my link website on FB

Tags: facebook, thumbnails, facebook-opengraph, sharing

I have been looking for couple day about this error but I could not find any solution.

When I am sharing my website on facebook using this url : https://getcleanio.com , the image thumbnail is not displayed.

I have including everything, about OP, in my header and here is a snippet :

`<meta property="og:title" content="Vos vêtements nettoyés et livrés en 24H | Cleanio" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://getcleanio.com/" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Cleanio est la nouvelle façon de faire nettoyer vos vêtements, quand vous le souhaitez et sans vous déplacer. Commandez en quelques clics, on s’occupe du reste !" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="https://getcleanio.com/images/logoFB.png" />
  <meta property="og:site_name" content="Cleanio" />
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="1397548253843587" />`

I also debug my url using : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ But it did not helped a lot. Instead I can see that the images recognized by the debugger is the Mixpanel logo and my logo on index which is not the one specified in my header.

If someone could help I would really appreciate.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Richard

Answer (score 0):

I fed the URL into Facebook's debugger and FB didn't find your meta tags. At the bottom of the debugger I chose "See exactly what our scraper sees for your URL" and sure enough your og meta tags don't appear. I looked at the source code and the head contents were - interesting, so I then fed the URL into the W3C validator and it turned up nine errors in the HTML including a variety of missing and poorly formed tags (including the head tag). Fix those errors so the page validates then try the FB debugger again.

http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fgetcleanio.com&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0